# Python - Why does my .read() not work on my .txt file? Nothing is outputted to the cmd line

Tags: python, printing, cmd

## Running

*I am running Python version 3.5, from the cmd prompt on Windows 7*

## What is in the .txt file and what the cmd outputs

[What the cmd prompt outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCnYF.png)

[What the .txt contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVi27.png)

## My current code

```
"""Opens a file and let\'s you read it and write to it"""

open_pls = open("text.txt", "a+")

#Main function
def read_write():
    program_running = True
    while program_running == True:
        choice = input("Write R for read, write W for write or write X for exit:")
        choice = choice.upper()
        if choice == "W":
            what_write = input("What do you want to write to the end of the file?:")
            open_pls.write(what_write)
            print("Succesfully written!")
            print("Running program again...")
            continue
        elif choice == "R":
            print("This file contains:")
            read_pls = open_pls.read()
            print(read_pls)
            print("Running program again...")
            continue
        elif choice == "X":
            program_running = False
            open_pls.close()
        else:
            print("That was not a valid command!")
            print("Running program again...")
            continue

run = input("Run the program? (Y/N):")
run = run.upper()
if run == "Y":
    read_write()
elif run == "N":
    input("Exit program? Press enter:")
else:
    input("Exit program? Press enter:")
```

## I think the problem lies somewhere in here

```
    elif choice == "R":
        print("This file contains:")
        read_pls = open_pls.read()
        print(read_pls)
        print("Running program again...")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the file with the `'a'` append mode, the OS gives you a file with the file position at the end of the file.

You could try to seek back to the start first, but it depends on your OS if that'll actually be permitted:

```
open_pls.seek(0)
read_pls = open_pls.read()
```

You may want to open the file in `'r+'` mode instead, and seek to the end when writing.

Comment: Thank you i understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file with `'a'` mode, the file is seeks to the end.  To get the contents of the file, you have to seek back to the beginning: `open_pls.seek(0)`.

Comment: `'a'` does **not** truncate the file. That's the whole point of that mode, you get to append. But the file position is set to the end, so writing actually appends.

Comment: Thank you i understand it now :)